# Trapezoidal Kernel in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, convolution

I wanted to implement a trapezoidal kernel in python(probably using numpy or scipy) for convolution just like the one which comes in the astropy module as Trapezoidal1Dkernel. I have tried convolving with a trapezoidal waveform but results were not satisfactory.

```
def trapzoid_signal(t, width=2., slope=1., amp=1., offs=0):
    global trasig
    trasig=[]
    trasig = slope*width*signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*t/width, width=0.5)/4.
    trasig+= slope*width/4.
    trasig[trasig>amp] = amp
    return trasig + offs
t = np.linspace(0, 32, 34)
trapzoid_signal(t, width=32, slope=1, amp=0.0322)
print(trasig)
z = scipy.signal.convolve(trasig,new)
```

If I print z it gives:

```
[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
```

I tried plotting z it gives nothing. Any help?

Comment: Please try to use a [mcve].  What code have you tried?  Do you have test input/output?

Comment: done. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!!! I did it. The thing as to why it was not plotting or printing values as `[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]` was removed by using the following code which I found on StackOverflow itself.

```
ind = np.where(~np.isnan(new))[0]
first, last = ind[0], ind[-1]
new[:first] = new[first]
new[last + 1:] = new[last]
```

Then it solved my problem. I not only got the values of z but also got my plot. Thanks to stackoverflow.com.